# How to align the strike through line

Tags: css

I have eBook, in that book one of the list has style to strike through the list with bullet. i can strike the bullet using the below coding but the alignment of the strike line is at the bottom of the bullet, i can't able to bring it into the top. can anyone help me to get out the solution.

Strike through coding @

```
ul.bullet3 li:before {
          margin: 0 0 0 -1em;
          width: 1em;
          content: '\2022';
          text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

Comment: PLease provide a jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<strike>` to strike the html list. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/strike

```
<ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li><strike>one</strike></li>
    <li>one</li>
</ul>
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/shanidkv/e3d6svmt/)

Comment: Thank you, but the strike element will not strike the bullet also in the list. hope i right correct if i am wrong.